# Navbar logo fails to render but does in body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've spent several days trying to figure out why the following code fails 
to find/render the mP_logo image for the header and footer navbars, but 
the image is found and rendered with link_to image_tag("mP_logo_36x55.png") 
on the same page.

BTW, in another, similar app, the same code has no problem rendering the 
logo in the navbars.

[image]

**Header**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top example6">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
      data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar6">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand text-hide" 
       src="mP_logo_36x55.png">mP logo
    </a>
  </div>
```

**Body**

```
<p class="well">   <%= link_to image_tag("mP_logo_36x55.png") %></p>
```

**Footer**
(source: https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/KwYGwq)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top example6">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
       data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar6">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand text-hide" 
       href="http://disputebills.com">Brand Text
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`src` is not a valid attribute for `<a>`.  Your image is not loading because you're never calling it via `<img>`

The correct way to insert an image via the `navbar-brand` class per Bootstrap's Documentation ( http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar ) is as follows:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img alt="Brand" src="...">
</a>
```

Comment: Such a simple oversight. Thanks for 'unblinding me'.